# Only first cookie in set-cookie header is set (after Firebase hosting rewrites to function)

Tags: express, cookies, http-headers, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to send multiple cookies in single response from express node back-end. Set-cookie header is set with values that seem to be valid but none of the cookies apart from the first one is ever stored. What might be causing this? Is it possible that some other headers are interfering somehow?

```js
app.post("/api/test", function(req, res) {
    res.cookie("age", "44");
    res.cookie("name", "ok");
    res.cookie("something", "else");
    res.send("cookies set");
});
```

Results in headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Etag: W/"b-AindM8n+eJQTR6jb7Hg8S4fG8qI"
Expires: Sat, 05 Oct 2019 16:18:12 GMT
Function-Execution-Id: r7d6qjgl5noi
Server: Google Frontend
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 051139bdc4cc753cad51c0dd3e89e0b8;o=1
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Length: 11
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 05 Oct 2019 16:18:12 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: age=44; path=/,name=ok; path=/,something=else; path=/
X-Served-By: cache-ams21036-AMS
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1570292292.302186,VS0,VE410
Vary: Origin,cookie,need-authorization, x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding
```

I would expect this to store 3 cookies in browser, but always only the first is saved.

EDIT:

After further investigation the cause of set-cookie header being written as comma separated one-liner ended up being Firebase hosting to function rewrite.

```
{
   "source": "/{,/**}",
   "function": "testingexpress"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation the cause of set-cookie header being written as comma separated one-liner ended up being Firebase hosting to function rewrite. Reported as bug.

Comment: Is there any further details on this? Any way to get around this? Thanks so much

Comment: FYI this bug has now been fixed. You should be able to send multiple Set-Cookie headers as expected. Would you mind updating the answer to reflect that?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Something changed for sure, I can't use __session cookie anymore on CloudRun behind Firebase hosting behind Cloudflare. Not sure exactly was is going on but it looks like my __session cookie is dropped now and can't log in my CMS anymore

Comment: I think I found why, in the message you say that you are now support multiple cookies in one line, but the date format of Expires contains a comma as per 
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.3.1
therefore it looks like you are splitting on the cookies on this comma in the middle of the date

Comment: Yup, we just came across this bug today. We're looking into it, but in the meantime I'd advise using max-age instead of expires in `Set-Cookie` headers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some versions of express may have an issue with generating invalid, or at least frequently incompatible, cookie headers ([syntax of a cookie header, RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2)) where more than one cookie appears a single Set-Cookie header.  The more standard way would be to provide multiple Set-Cookie headers in the response.

Notably, from the above RFC, is also this [excerpt](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-3):

> Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into
> a single header field.  The usual mechanism for folding HTTP headers
> fields (i.e., as defined in [RFC2616]) might change the semantics of
> the Set-Cookie header field because the %x2C (",") character is used
> by Set-Cookie in a way that conflicts with such folding.

This document notes a possible workaround, and is from around 2014: http://www.connecto.io/blog/nodejs-express-how-to-set-multiple-cookies-in-the-same-response-object/

I was not able to replicate this with express 4.17.1 (similar code generated multiple Set-Cookie headers).  It looks like the behavior may have been changed around 4.13.0: https://github.com/expressjs/express/commit/5915894af3f14e75dd3121fdc2d92ae55206e398

I'd look at either updating your version of Express, or using the workaround in the above linked article.

Comment: I'm running the same node version and tried the workaround still with no luck. So I figured the cause must have been somewhere else and realized i have been running express on Firebase functions.I tested this locally and it works flawlessly. What i'm guessing is that deployed version of Firebase rewrites headers and formats set-cookie into outdated, comma separated format.

Comment: @llusi Interesting.  With either a deployed or locally served firebase function to test this I do not see the rewrites.  If you are indeed seeing a difference, that might be worth contacting support about.

Your supplied code, though, doesn't appear to be a firebase function. (it uses "app.post" which doesn't generally show up in firebase functions).

Comment: after further testing the cause ended up being firebase function being redirected from hosting rewrite such as 
`{
                "source": "/app/**",
                "function": "testingexpress"
            }
`
functions without hosting rewrites turned out to be working fine

Comment: Seems like that might be worth [reporting](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs)

Comment: @llusi Since you have found the answer by yourself, it would be good if you post the answer and accept it, in order to close this thread.